# incorrect position from .offset()

Tags: jquery

I have a website that I'm trying to overlay one picture on top of another, I get the position of the current element using

```
var position = $(".portfolio-items a").offset();
```

and then set the new element to be in the same position but this time with a static positioning.  I found that it was ending up off the bottom of the page so for that reason I subtracted the result of

```
$(document).scrollTop();
```

from the top position but for some reason the item is still ending up 135px too far down the page.

Any ideas where that 135px is coming from?

you can see the website at www.pixelcoding.co.uk and to test it simply click the ajlcomputers portfolio image (the first one).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code ? My guess, the 135px come from parent element with position: relative;

Comment: maybe you want to use .position() instead of .offset() as .position() will result in positions relative to the parent's offset rather than the document which might help in your situation

Comment: The code can all be seen from the site, these elements are quite far down the page so I don't want to paste the entire contents of the page to this page.

Shouldn't the position returned by .offset() be the actual position on the page so any relative placement would be irrelevant wouldn't it?

Comment: I want to know the exact position on the page rather than relevant to anything else so that I can overlay the second image using fixed positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this, when I inspected the element more closely with firebug I found that the  that I was targeting was only showing in the bottom 20px of the image for some reason (the image is 150px high) so that's the missing 130px.  Not sure why it's happening but to resolve it I simply targeted the img rather than the a and now it works fine.